# Using C# to programmatically find, and populate bookmarks in a Word 2010 Add-In

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ms-word

I have a Microsoft word 2010 add-in project in visual studio, I just followed the MSDN guide to making a new tab with custom functionality on the ribbon. I've done some googling, but I cant seem to find any examples (or if its even possible) to use the C# to find a bookmark, then use the bookmarks name in an SQL query and populate it. The documents I am working with can have dozens of bookmarks, and there are hundreds of documents. Automating this process is a high priority.

Comment: Well, you [get the bookmarks in the document from the `Bookmarks` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.bookmarks(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So basically if you want to automate word documents (building word document templates via word bookmarks)  Here's how I normally go about doing it.

- Copy The Template
- Work On The Template
- Save In Desired Format
- Delete Template Copy

Each of the sections that you are replacing within your word document you have to insert a bookmark for that location (easiest way to input text in an area).

I always create a function to accomplish this, and I end up passing in the path - as well as all of the text to replace my in-document bookmarks. The function call can get long sometimes, but it works for me.

```
Application app = new Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open("sDocumentCopyPath.docx");


if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists("bookmark_1"))
    {
        object oBookMark = "bookmark_1";
        doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMark).Range.Text = My Text To Replace bookmark_1;
    }
    if (doc.Bookmarks.Exists("bookmark_2"))
    {
        object oBookMark = "bookmark_2";
        doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oBookMark).Range.Text = My Text To Replace bookmark_2;
    }

            doc.ExportAsFixedFormat("myNewPdf.pdf", WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);

((_Document)doc).Close();
((_Application)app).Quit();
```

This code should get you up and running unless you want to pass in all the values into a function.

Sometimes if you have large amounts of fields you can build objects/classes to contain the values.

If you need more examples I'm working on a blog post as well, so I have a lot more detail if this wasn't clear enough for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spire.Doc` or `FreeSpire.Doc` library for this purpose. I have a github repo, that I showed an example how to working it.

```
using Spire.Doc;
using Spire.Doc.Documents;
using Spire.Doc.Fields;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace WorkingDocAndPdf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sourceFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SourceFilePath"];

            var saveFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaveFilePath"];

            var document = new Document(sourceFilePath);

            var bookmarksNavigator = new BookmarksNavigator(document);

            bookmarksNavigator.MoveToBookmark("client_name");
            bookmarksNavigator.ReplaceBookmarkContent("Ramil", true);

            bookmarksNavigator.MoveToBookmark("client_taxno");
            bookmarksNavigator.ReplaceBookmarkContent("VN-12300254178XY6", true);

            bookmarksNavigator.MoveToBookmark("amount");
            bookmarksNavigator.ReplaceBookmarkContent("871 AZN", true);

            bookmarksNavigator.MoveToBookmark("date");
            bookmarksNavigator.ReplaceBookmarkContent(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), true);

            //It is for picture
            var sealPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SealPath"];

            bookmarksNavigator.MoveToBookmark("seal", true, true);

            var section = document.AddSection();

            var image = Image.FromFile(sealPath);

            var paragraph = section.AddParagraph();

            paragraph.AppendPicture(image);

            bookmarksNavigator.InsertParagraph(paragraph);

            document.Sections.Remove(section);

            if (!Directory.Exists(saveFilePath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(saveFilePath);

            var saveFileFullPath = $"{saveFilePath}\\{Guid.NewGuid()}.pdf";
             
            //It is for refresh cross reference bookmark, that you can use one bookmark on different location in document. In word shortcut it is `CTRL A + F9` 
            document.IsUpdateFields = true;

            document.SaveToFile(saveFileFullPath, FileFormat.PDF);
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, you can visit my github repo: [WorkingDocAndPdf_FreeSpireDoc](https://github.com/ramilaliyev007/WorkingDocAndPdf_FreeSpireDoc/tree/main/WorkingDocAndPdf)

My article about FreeSpire.Doc (but written in Azerbaijani): [C# working Word and PDF files. Print forms](https://ramilaliyev.com/az/blog/details/9/c-da-word-doc-docx-ve-pdf-fayllari-ile-ish-chap-formalari)